# OpenSSL Security Fix in Wildfly

Tags: openssl, wildfly

i have a lot of wildfly  instances (10, 18, 26) running on client side servers. The OpenSSL Team announced a critical security fix for this week:
https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-announce/2022-October/000238.html

We get a lot of questions if the wildfly is affected by this or not.
I know that the wildfly uses an internal openssl binding jar (https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-openssl) but don't know if its affected or not. As i understand, the jar itself uses native openssl libraries, installed on the system. For linux systems, its clear. Openssl is mostly installed.

But on Windows, in many cases, there is no openssl installed. What libraries ist wildfly using instead for ssl capabilities?

Does anyone knows whether wildfly is affected or not?

Thanks
zwaem

Comment: WildFly doesn't use OpenSSL by default. Have you enabled it? If so make sure you patch the openssl installed in your OS.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I thougt it is automatically enabled if you use tls/ssl capababilities like https. Am i wrong?

Comment: No, you have to enable it https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#OpenSSL. Also, WildFly itself does not need to be patched, only your local install of OpenSSL.